# How can it be that the std::vector distance Function gives a higher value than .size()?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

I have the following code, where `myFields` is a std::set of pairs and currentSet is a std::vector of pairs, which has a very strange behavior: After a iteration where the condition is true, the size of `currentSet` gets increased as I expect from 1 to 2, but very strangely the distance in the for loop from the current iterator does not go from 1 to 2 as well as I expect, but suddenly to 6. This causes my code to crash after the next iteration, because there are not more than 2 elements in the vector, so it will try to read unallocated memory.

```
vector<pair<int,int>> currentSet;

currentSet.push_back( *(myFields.begin()) );
myFields.erase( myFields.begin() );

for ( auto iterator=currentSet.begin(); iterator != currentSet.end(); ++iterator ) {

    set<pair<int,int>>::iterator topright = myFields.find( pair<int,int>( i, j+1 ) );

    if ( topright != myFields.end() ) {
        cout << "size " << currentSet.size() << endl;    // gives 1
        cout << "dist to end " << distance(iterator, currentSet.end()) << endl;    // gives 1
        UniqueInsertion(currentSet, *topright, myFields );
        cout << "size " << currentSet.size() << endl;    // gives 2
        cout << "dist to end " << distance(iterator, currentSet.end()) << endl;    // gives 6!?


    }
}
```

Where `UniqueInsertion` is the following function:

```
void UniqueInsertion(vector<pair<int,int>> &vect, const pair<int,int> &elem, set<pair<int,int>> &fields) {

  if(find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), elem) == vect.end()) {
      vect.push_back(elem); 
      fields.erase(elem);
  }
}
```

This problem has only shown up when I changed the Sets from std::set to std::vector, which was necessary because I need back insertion for the loop to work this way. I have not the slightest idea what causes this behavior and would be very grateful for explanation to how this happens, and of course what I can do to fix it.

Cheers!

Comment: `std::set::insert` doesn't invalidate iterator, whereas `std::vector::push_back` may (and does in your case).

Comment: Your compiler will provide some way of checking your iterators are valid. Use it. For example, with GCC you should define `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` when compiling each file, and it will tell you when you use iterators after they have become invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're use `push_back` on `currentSet`:

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated.

Comment: but the size of std::vector can be dynamically changed, so I don't understand why I push_back() should be an issue. Also, what is capacity() and why will it not grow with size? Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Exactly, and changing it dynamically is what invalidates your iterator. `capacity` is the current in memory size.

Comment: So, how can I solve this issue? Is there a std:: container suited better for my needs? Or do I have to change capacity manually somehow?

Comment: Don't use `distance` (or *anything*) on a possibly invalidated iterator. Setting your [`capacity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) manually to a value that won't be exceeded is one way.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the quick answer. Will try it with .reserve() then, even if that is not really a nice way to solve it in my eyes.

Comment: Never mind the `std::distance` call, using `push_back` or *anything* that could invalidate iterators inside a `for` loop using the same container's iterators is a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, `std::vector` stores its array **contiguously** in memory.

For that, it allocates an array of an arbitrary size (to avoid to reallocate at each `push_back()`).
And when we have performed as many `push_back()` as the available allocated space, the `std::vector` reallocates a bigger array to be able to add the new element.

The problem is here, as the `std::vector` stores its elements contiguously in memory, it needs to copy the already existing data in the new location (the bigger array). Then, the old array is released.
Therefore, if you have an iterator pointing to an element of the vector, after the reallocation, the iterator becomes invalidated and points to a free memory.

Comment: I see, even though I don't undestand why this is not resolved somehow. Anyways, do you have a recommendation on how to solve this in my case?

Comment: @justsomerandomguy I would advise you to never change the capacity of a `std::vector` while you are iterating over it. I think you should either use temporary containers or refactor your code.

Comment: what do you mean by temporary container?

Comment: @justsomerandomguy I mean that to avoid to add elements in a container while iterating over it, you can for example store the contents into another container and append it to the original one at the end of the iterative process. But in your case, it seems that you better have to refactor your code.